# Sending numbers greater than 256 over serial connection

Tags: serial-port, arduino

A partial solution to my problem is given here
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=97846.0

But using the Wire class in my arduino code, and don't know how to modify.

here is my complete arduino code. Can any arduino experts chime in?

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x04
int number = 0;
int state = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);         // start serial for output
    // initialize i2c as slave
    Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);

    // define callbacks for i2c communication
    Wire.onReceive(receiveData);
    Wire.onRequest(sendData);

    Serial.println("Ready!");
}

void loop() {
    delay(100);
}

// callback for received data
void receiveData(int byteCount){

    while(Wire.available()) {
        number = Wire.read();
        Serial.print("data received: ");
        Serial.println(number);

        if (number == 1){

            if (state == 0){
                digitalWrite(13, HIGH); // set the LED on
                state = 1;
            }
            else{
                digitalWrite(13, LOW); // set the LED off
                state = 0;
            }
         }
     }
}

// callback for sending data
void sendData(){
    Wire.write(number);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using an Arduino Uno.

The Arduino Uno stores an `int` as a 16-bit or 2 bytes value.

`Serial.write()` only write a `byte` so you need to tweak it a little.

You could use this kind of function:

```
void writeInt(unsigned int value){
    Wire.write(lowByte(value));
    Wire.write(highByte(value));
}
```

You first write the `lowByte()` and then the `highByte`.

Note that you then on the slave you'll need to transform two `bytes` into an `int`. You can do that this way:

```
unsigned int value = highByte * 256 + lowByte;
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: thanks. so Wire.write(number); would get replaced with Wire.write(lowByte(value));
    Wire.write(highByte(value));. But wouldn't I need to check first if the value was greater than 1 byte(255)?

Comment: no because `number` is an `int`. Therefore it is already using 2 bytes regardless of its value. So you just need to use `void writeInt(unsigned int value)`